# Can I use @ObservedObject to make instant View updates?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a Song View where I can add or remove a song as favourite, all works well and the update takes place, now what I want is a View where I can see list of all songs that are favourites, so I use an @ObservedObject property wrapper and then use it to display the list …

The problem comes when I go to a songs page and add/remove a song as favourite, the favourite View is unable to redraw it self and continues to show old list of favourites, however if I restart the app it works, how can I overcome this, the @ObservedObject wrapper must be watching any changes to the @Published property which the array of songs is , so why is it not working instantly, thanks …

Where I define ObservableObject class

```
struct Song: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var album: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var genre: String
    var artist: String
    init(name: String, album: String, isFavorite: Bool, genre: String, artist: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.album = album
        self.artist = artist
        self.genre = genre
        self.isFavorite = isFavorite
    }
    static let `default` = Song(name: "demo", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo")
   
}

class Songs: ObservableObject {
    var songsData: [Song] =
            [
                Song(name: "demo", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
                Song(name: "demo", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
                Song(name: "demo", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
                Song(name: "demo", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
                Song(name: "demo", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
            ]

    @Published var songs = [Song]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(songs) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "demosongs")
            }
        }
    }
    
   
    
   
    
   
    init(){
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "demosongs") {
               if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Song].self, from: savedItems) {
                   songs = decodedItems
                   return
               }
           }
           songs = songsData
       }
}
```

Where I add/remove favourites

```
struct SongView: View {
    @Binding var song: Song
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(song.name)")

        Button(song.isFavorite ? "Remove from favorite" : "add to favorites") {
            song.isFavorite.toggle()
        }
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

where I try and display favourites

```
struct FavoritesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var songs: Songs
    
    
   
    var body: some View {
        List(songs.songs) { song in
                  if song.isFavorite  {
                      Text(song.name)
                  }
        }
    }
}
```

// How I use SongView

```
struct AlbumView: View {
    @ObservedObject var songData: Songs
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Image("cover")
                .resizable().opacity(0.5)
                .zIndex(1)
       
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach($songData.songs) { $song in
                        NavigationLink {
                            SongView(song: $song)
                            
                        } label: {
                            customText(image: "joinus", str: song.name)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        }
                    }
                }.padding()
            }.zIndex(2)
        }
        
    }
    
    func customText(image: String, str: String) ->  some View {
        Group {
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 150)
                    .overlay(Image(image)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 150))
                Text(str)
                    .scaledFont(name: "Gothic", size: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous).fill(Color.gray))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show where and how you use/call `SongView`

Comment: I added code at end of question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some example code that lets you change the `song.isFavorite` and
have it reflected in `AlbumView`. It shows `AlbumView` is updated as you
press `song.isFavorite.toggle()` in `SongView`. It really depends on how you use your code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var songs = Songs() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {  // <-- here
            AlbumView(songData: songs)  // <-- here
        }
    }
}

struct AlbumView: View {
    @ObservedObject var songData: Songs
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("cover")
                .resizable().opacity(0.5)
                .zIndex(1)
       
            ScrollView {
                VStack (spacing: 44) {
                    ForEach($songData.songs) { $song in
                        NavigationLink {
                            SongView(song: $song)
                        } label: {
                            // for testing
                            Text(song.name) + Text(song.isFavorite ? " is favorite" : " is NOT favorite")
                         //   customText(image: "joinus", str: song.name)
                         //       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        }
                    }
                }.padding()
            }.zIndex(2)
        }
    }
    
    func customText(image: String, str: String) ->  some View {
         Group {
             VStack {
                 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                     .fill(.blue)
                     .padding()
                     .frame(width: 300, height: 150)
                     .overlay(Image(image)
                         .resizable()
                         .frame(width: 300, height: 150))
                 Text(str)
                  //   .scaledFont(name: "Gothic", size: 20)
                 //    .foregroundColor(.white)
                     .padding()
                     .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous).fill(Color.gray))
             }
         }
     }
}

struct SongView: View {
    @Binding var song: Song
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // -- here for testing
            Text(song.name) + Text(song.isFavorite ? " is favorite" : " is NOT favorite")
            Button(song.isFavorite ? "Remove from favorite" : "add to favorites") {
                song.isFavorite.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Song: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var album: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var genre: String
    var artist: String
    init(name: String, album: String, isFavorite: Bool, genre: String, artist: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.album = album
        self.artist = artist
        self.genre = genre
        self.isFavorite = isFavorite
    }
    static let `default` = Song(name: "demo", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo")
    
}

class Songs: ObservableObject {
    var songsData: [Song] =
    [
        Song(name: "demo1", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
        Song(name: "demo2", album: "demo", isFavorite: true, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
        Song(name: "demo3", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
        Song(name: "demo4", album: "demo", isFavorite: true, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
        Song(name: "demo5", album: "demo", isFavorite: false, genre: "demo", artist: "demo"),
    ]
    
    @Published var songs = [Song]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(songs) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "demosongs")
            }
        }
    }
    
    init(){
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "demosongs") {
            if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Song].self, from: savedItems) {
                songs = decodedItems
                return
            }
        }
        songs = songsData
    }
}
```